# Cast pl.Date to Unix epoch

Tags: python, datetime, python-polars

Trying to convert a pl.Date column to UNIX epoch as is, without any timezone offset:

```
import polars as pl; import datetime

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {'Date': [datetime.datetime.now().date()]}
)
```

Correct time (00:00:00) when converted to Datetime:

```
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("Date").cast(pl.Datetime).keep_name()
)
>> 2023-06-10 00:00:00
```

Incorrect time when casting to timestamp:

```
df = df.with_columns(
    pl.col("Date").cast(pl.Datetime).dt.timestamp("ms").truediv(1_000).keep_name()
)
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(df["Date"][0])
>> datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 10, 8, 0)
```

As suggested, without casting to Datetime:

```
df = df.with_columns(
    pl.col("Date").dt.timestamp("ms").truediv(1_000).keep_name()
)
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(df["Date"][0])
>> datetime.datetime(2023, 6, 10, 8, 0)
```

Comment: So, what timezone is it supposed to be in?  You can't just ignore time zones.  A UNIX timestamp is in GMT.

Comment: It should be in the format pl.Datetime returns. The input can also be a simple date string without any timezone information giving the same result. So it appears dt.timestamp internally does a GMT -> localtime conversion as it assumes the 00:00 supplied is GMT?

Comment: It looks like I could work around this by using utcfromtimestamp

Comment: side note, utcfromtimestamp can lead to more unexpected results, [better avoid it](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that vanilla Python datetime defaults to *local* time if you don't set a time zone (naive datetime). In contrast, polars assumes naive datetime to resemble UTC (as pandas does as well).

Keep it consistent by setting the time zone, e.g. UTC:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {'Date': [datetime.now(timezone.utc).date()]}
)

df = df.with_columns(
    pl.col("Date").cast(pl.Datetime).dt.timestamp("ms").truediv(1_000).alias("Unix")
)

print(df)
# shape: (1, 2)
# ┌────────────┬──────────┐
# │ Date       ┆ Unix     │
# │ ---        ┆ ---      │
# │ date       ┆ f64      │
# ╞════════════╪══════════╡
# │ 2023-06-10 ┆ 1.6864e9 │
# └────────────┴──────────┘

print(datetime.fromtimestamp(df["Unix"][0], timezone.utc))
# 2023-06-10 00:00:00+00:00
```